# GSON Date Format - Handling null date in the JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, date, gson

I am trying to convert the JSON to a custom bean. But I am facing issue when the date value is null in the JSON.

Valid JSON String, it is getting converted with out any issue as both from and to date has values:

```
{"title":"1201 Box Title 1","fromdate":"01/02/2017","description":"1201 Box Title 1","todate":"01/26/2017"}
```

JSON String with Error: Where from date is empty

```
{"title":"1201 Box Title 1","fromdate":"","description":"1201 Box Title 1","todate":"01/26/2017"}
```

Java code used for Initialization:

```
 Gson testGson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").create();
 MyTestBean myTestBean = testGson.fromJson(jsonString, MyTestBean.class);
```

In the bean fromdate and todate attributes are declared with the "Date" datatype

Error Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:59)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642)
at JSONConverter.main(JSONConverter.java:15)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
    ... 10 more
```

Could anyone please let me how to handle this issue in the right way.

One way I am trying to overcome the issue is as below, but wanted to know if there is any inbuilt option in GSON itsself to handle the null date:

1. Declare the from and to dates in bean as String datatype
2. Write a custom getter method in the bean which will do the parsing before returning the date which will be used by code using this bean

Comment: You have an empty string, not `null`

Comment: Does that mean if we pass null GSON will take care of this?

Comment: Probably not. You might get a NullPointerException instead of a ParseException

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, passing null solved the issue. JSON string which is working is as below: {"title":"1201 Box Title 1","fromdate":null,"description":"1201 Box Title 1","todate":"01/26/2017"}   In the bean it is setting as null we need to handle while using that bean value. UI also need to make change to pass it as null instead of empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidating the comments came from my question and placing the answer from those comments:

JSON string which worked fine with out any parsing issue is:

```
{"title":"1201 Box Title 1","fromdate":null,"description":"1201 Box Title 1","todate":"01/26/2017"}
```

After adding the required condition in the JS which is constructing the JSON to pass null instead of empty string fixed the issue.

Thanks @cricket_007 for pointing the issue that needs to be resolved.